# how to make dropdown in pyro cms

Tags: php, dropdown, pyro

I have file "header.html" in partial folder, here my code

```
        <ul class="sf-menu" id="mainMenu">
        {{ shoesmart:showMenu group="header" indent="tab"}}
        <li><a href="{{ url }}" class="{{ class }}">{{ name }}</a>
            {{ if children }}
            <ul>
            {{ children }}
                <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
            {{ /children }}
            </ul>
            {{ endif }}
        </li>
        {{/shoesmart:showMenu}}
        </ul>
```

but when I refresh in browser, just show main menu, its mean that the submenu didn't show. Should I change my code ? or I also add new table for submenu in my database?

**From Comments:**

and I have file "shoesmart.php" in plugins folder:

```
function showMenu() { $return = ''; $menu_list = $this->db->select('*,CONCAT(pua.type,"/",pua.keyword) as path',false) ->from('menu mn') ->join('product_url_alias pua','mn.url_alias_id=pua.url_alias_id','LEFT') ->where('status',1) ->get() ->result_array(); foreach ($menu_list as $result) { $return[] = array( 'name' => $result['name'], 'url' => BASE_URL.'home/'.$result['path'] ); } return $return; }
```

and my table name in database is "default_menu" that have structure:

`menu_id url_alias_id name status parent_id 1 868 Men 1 0 2 869 woman 1 0`

Comment: and I have file "shoesmart.php" in plugins folder:

function showMenu()
{
    $return = '';

    $menu_list = $this->db->select('*,CONCAT(pua.type,"/",pua.keyword) as path',false)
             ->from('menu mn')
             ->join('product_url_alias pua','mn.url_alias_id=pua.url_alias_id','LEFT')
             ->where('status',1)
             ->get()
             ->result_array();

    foreach ($menu_list as $result) {
        $return[] = array(
            'name'  => $result['name'],
            'url'   => BASE_URL.'home/'.$result['path']
            );
    }
    return $return;
}

Comment: and my table name in database is "default_menu" that have structure:

menu_id     url_alias_id    name    status  parent_id
1           868             Men     1       0
2           869             woman   1       0